# Redefining a let'd variable in Clojure loop

Tags: clojure, let, function

OK. I've been tinkering with Clojure and I continually run into the same problem. Let's take this little fragment of code:

```
(let [x 128]
  (while (> x 1)
    (do
      (println x)
      (def x (/ x 2)))))
```

Now I expect this to print out a sequence starting with 128 as so:

```
128
64
32
16
8
4
2
```

Instead, it's an infinite loop, printing 128 over and over. Clearly my intended side effect isn't working.

So how am I supposed to redefine the value of x in a loop like this? I realize this may not be Lisp like (I could use an anonymous function that recurses on it's self, perhaps), but if I don't figure out how to set variable like this, I'm going to go mad.

My other guess would be to use set!, but that gives "Invalid assignment target", since I'm not in a binding form.

Please, enlighten me on how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`def` defines a toplevel var, even if you use it in a function or inner loop of some code.  What you get in `let` are not vars.  Per [the documentation for `let`](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#let):

> **Locals created with let are not variables. Once created their values never change!**

(Emphasis not mine.)  You don't need mutable state for your example here; you could use `loop` and `recur`.

```
(loop [x 128]
  (when (> x 1)
    (println x)
    (recur (/ x 2))))
```

If you wanted to be fancy you could avoid the explicit `loop` entirely.

```
(let [xs (take-while #(> % 1) (iterate #(/ % 2) 128))]
  (doseq [x xs] (println x)))
```

If you *really* wanted to use mutable state, an [atom](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms) might work.

```
(let [x (atom 128)]
  (while (> @x 1)
    (println @x)
    (swap! x #(/ %1 2))))
```

(You don't need a `do`; `while` wraps its body in an explicit one for you.)  If you *really, really* wanted to do this with [vars](https://clojure.org/reference/vars) you'd have to do something horrible like this.

```
(with-local-vars [x 128]
  (while (> (var-get x) 1)
    (println (var-get x))
    (var-set x (/ (var-get x) 2))))
```

But this is very ugly and it's not idiomatic Clojure at all. To use Clojure effectively you should try to stop thinking in terms of mutable state.  It will definitely drive you crazy trying to write Clojure code in a non-functional style. After a while you may find it to be a pleasant surprise how seldom you actually need mutable variables.

Comment: Thanks. I realize my way wasn't Lispy, as side effects are frowned upon. I was hacking through something (a Project Euler problem) and couldn't get that simple test case to work, proving I didn't understand something. Thanks for the help. I forgot loop could hold recur, that works very cleanly (without the extra function doing recursion).

Comment: Side effects are Lispy depending which Lisp you're looking at.  In Common Lisp you'd get away with (loop for x = 128 then (/ x 2) while (> x 1) do (print x)).  But side effects aren't Clojurish.

Comment: It's very old one But this is a very good answer, I'm new to Clojure this saved me from hours of struggling with the same problem. Thank you very much @BrianCarper

Answer (score 13):

Vars (that's what you get when you "def" something) aren't meant to be reassigned (but can be):

```
user=> (def k 1)
#'user/k
user=> k
1
```

There's nothing stopping you from doing:

```
user=> (def k 2)
#'user/k
user=> k
2
```

If you want a thread-local settable "place" you can use "binding" and "set!":

```
user=> (def j) ; this var is still unbound (no value)
#'user/j
user=> j
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Var user/j is unbound. (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
user=> (binding [j 0] j)
0
```

So then you can write a loop like this:

```
user=> (binding [j 0]
         (while (< j 10)
           (println j)
           (set! j (inc j))))
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
nil
```

But I think this is pretty unidiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

If you think that having mutable local variables in pure functions would be a nice convenient feature that does no harm, because the function still remains pure, you might be interested in this mailing list discussion where Rich Hickey explains his reasons for removing them from the language. [Why not mutable locals?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/PCKzXweeDeY)

Relevant part:

> If locals were variables, i.e. mutable, then closures could close over
>   mutable state, and, given that closures can escape (without some extra
>   prohibition on same), the result would be thread-unsafe. And people 
>   would certainly do so, e.g. closure-based pseudo-objects. The result 
>   would be a huge hole in Clojure's approach.
>
> Without mutable locals, people are forced to use recur, a functional 
>   looping construct. While this may seem strange at first, it is just as
>   succinct as loops with mutation, and the resulting patterns can be 
>   reused elsewhere in Clojure, i.e. recur, reduce, alter, commute etc 
>   are all (logically) very similar. Even though I could detect and 
>   prevent mutating closures from escaping, I decided to keep it this way
>   for consistency. Even in the smallest context, non-mutating loops are 
>   easier to understand and debug than mutating ones. In any case, Vars 
>   are available for use when appropriate.

The majority of the subsequent posts concerns implementing a `with-local-vars` macro ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could more idiomatically use `iterate` and `take-while` instead,

```
user> (->> 128
           (iterate #(/ % 2))
           (take-while (partial < 1)))

(128 64 32 16 8 4 2)
user>
```

Comment: Very elegant..!